# Cant match a function with an array in same class(no attribute)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
    import random
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

gladList = np.empty((128,5))              
class Gladiators:

def __init__(self,name1,hp,atd,armor,accuracy):
    self.name1=name1
    self.hp=hp
    self.atd=atd
    self.armor=armor
    self.accuracy=accuracy

@staticmethod    
def createRobot(x):
    for i in range(x):
        gladList[i]=(i,random.randint(1000,1500),random.randint(40,80),random.randint(0,100),random.randint(60,100))
        print(gladList[i])

def info(self):
    print("Analyzing Gladiator...")
    print("Name:",self.name1,"Health:",self.hp,"AD:",self.atd,"Armor:",self.armor,"Accuracy:",self.accuracy)

def isAlive(self):
    pass
def fight(self):
    pass


Gladiators.createRobot(128)  g1=gladList[41]  ig1=Gladiators.info(g1)  print(ig1)

> Error: line 27, in info
    print("Name:",self.name1,"Health:",self.hp,"AD:",self.atd,"Armor:",self.armor,"Accuracy:",self.accuracy)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'name1'
>
```

I guess i should use self instead of using static method but im still getting error anyways

Comment: You're passing `g1` which in an `ndarray` to `info`. g1 doesnt have an attribute name1. You need to instantaite a gladiator object and call info with thar object. Consider revising classes and OOP in python.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of the info method is wrong. It's not a static method, so you can't call it on the class.

You have two options:

1. Call info properly

```py
gladiator = Gladiators.createRobot(128)
print(gladiator.info())
```

2. Redefine info as a static method that takes a gladiator as an argument (Warning: I don't necessarily think this is a good idea).

```py
...
@staticmethod
def info(some_gladiator):
    print("Analyzing Gladiator...")
    print(
        "Name:", some_gladiator.name1,
        "Health:", some_gladiator.hp, 
        "AD:", some_gladiator.atd,
        "Armor:", some_gladiator.armor,
        "Accuracy:", some_gladiator.accuracy
   )
...

gladiator = Gladiators.createRobot(128)
print(Gladiators.info(gladiator))
```